# Stable 12V 1.5A

Tags: voltage-regulator, buck, switching-regulator, linear-regulator, buck-boost

I'm in need of a stable 12V 1.5A power which I could carry with myself.

One way of doing it would be to strap, say, 12x 1.2V rechargeable batteries and use LM317. But then I read about buck converters and that there are up-/down-/up+down switching regulators and that they are much more power efficient.

My question is, what would be there best way to proceed? Is it better to provide 9V and step it up, or 14.4V and step it down, or 12V and use up-and-down regular like S18V20F12?

And I'm not familiar with regulators so if the input source is a battery how many amperes does it provide? In other words, how to make sure I get 1.5A?

Also, I would like to be able to drain the stable power for, say, 10 hours.

Comment: How long do you need this to last? Almost surely, the batteries themselves will dominate your cost and weight, regardless of how you design the regulator. So find the best batteries you can to store the amount of energy you need. Then figure out how to regulate it to the voltage your load needs.

Comment: @ThePhoton Good point about the time, made an edit to the question. As you indicated, the weight and cost is unavoidable so I would like to know how to proceed, if I already had the batteries. I mean, I would like to make it work correctly first, and then worry about cost and weight.

Comment: What is your load? "Stable" - how stable?

Comment: If you already have the batteries, what voltage do they supply fully charged and fully discharged, and how many cells do you have (to figure out how many ways there are to rearrange them)?

Comment: @ThePhoton Sorry, bad wording. I don't have any batteries yet, I tried to say that I worry about the regulator more as I can always buy more batteries.

Comment: @Transistor It's for a servo actuator. I guess it doesn't have to be super stable but I just want to be sure as it is quite delicate.

Comment: I have never used these but I imagine the 12 V is feeding the motor and there is no stability requirement. The built-in controller will probably run on a 5 V supply and will have a built-in regulator. I doubt that there is a need for stability as long as it can supply the required current.

Comment: @Transistor Interesting! If it was as you say, are you suggesting I should use a "current" regulator?

Comment: Like I said, the batteries will dominate cost, weight, and physical volume. Choose the batteries first. Then start designing the power regulator. There's no point trying to give a general answer to this question until you've picked the batteries. (Or you might just find that batteries able to supply 18 W for 10 hours all by themselves are too big to be considered hand-carryable)

Comment: @ThePhoton Ok, but how to fix the batteries, if I don't know if the voltage should be above or below the required value?

Comment: It doesn't matter if the battery voltage is below or above 12 V. Or even if they're sometimes above and sometimes below. You can design a power regulator to deal with it. The difference in cost/performance/weight/price will be negligible compared to the differences due to the kind of batteries you choose.

Comment: @ThePhoton So it is comparable to step up from 9V to step down from 14.4V? That was my question, if it doesn't matter I could then decide what to do next. I was just assuming one way could be more efficient that the other...

Comment: @ThePhoton Also, let's say I have 1.2V 1500mAh baterries. To get 12V I would need 10 of them and to get 10 hours of 1.5A I would need 100 of them? Roughly?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: Now you know you need ~100 cells. You can still decide to connect them (for example) in 8 strings of 12 (and step down) or 12 strings of 8 (and step up). But the best improvements you're going to get to this design are going to come from shopping around to see if you can get (for example) 1800 mAhr cells for the same price, or 2200 mAhr cells for less than 1.5x the price, or whatever.

Comment: @ThePhoton Ok, thank you! So to summarize to see if I understood: the difference between step down and step up is negligible and by using batteries and a regulator I still should be able to draw (at least) 1.5A. Correct?

Comment: Yes, compared to the cost of the batteries, the cost of the regulator will be pretty small, regardless of whether it's step-up, step-down or up-down.

Comment: @ThePhoton Please, very final thing. The price for the regulators is small compared to the price of batteries, I get that. But for a given set of batteries (like you said, 12x8 or 8x12), which configuration is going to last longer? Or is the difference also negligible? Also, if you care to write it up as an answer I would accept it. Thank a lot once more!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know enough about battery charge management to give you a good detailed answer. If you're using primary batteries, being able to step up will let you discharge the batteries more deeply. With rechargables, you might not want to do that for safety reasons.